# I want to declare for loop a variable to insert it into mysql easily

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli

I have this to get some content from a web, at the end there is a forloop and I want all forloop value to get stored in one variable so I can easily insert them into mysql database.

```
$url = "http://sms.hindijokes.co";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
@$doc->loadHTML ("<html><body>".$html. "</body></html>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query1 = "//h2[@class='entry-title']/a";
$query2 = "//div[@class='entry-content'][1]/p";
$entries1 = $xpath->query($query1);
$entries2 = $xpath->query($query2);
$var1 =  $entries1->item(0)->textContent;
$var2 =  $entries2->item(0)->textContent;
echo "$var1"; 
echo "<br>";
$f = $entries2->length;
for($i = 0; $i < $f; $i++){
    $var3 =  $entries2->item($i)->textContent;
    echo $var3;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Trivially, you could just make a database with an id column and an html column of type LONGTEXT and insert $html into it. You need to be more specific.

Comment: at the end for loop generates 5-10 lines of <p> element depending on $i , i want the all line to get stored into mysql .., or is their any way i can make them a variable?

Comment: echo just outputs text strings. Instead of echoing them as output, try assigning them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please insert `$all = "";` before for loop. Then, don't use "echo" in the for loop, change it like this: `$all .= $var3 . " - ";`. After that, you can echo `$all` or add it to database...